# use async/await but return Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, promise

```
    const placeObjFunc = async () => {
          let placeObj = await getLongLat(parseStr.address);
          let lat = placeObj.lat;
          let lng = placeObj.lng;
          console.log("lat, lng: ", lat, lng, typeof lat);
          return [lat, lng];
        };
    let lat_lng = placeObjFunc();
```

result is below:
$ lat, lng:  31.7330889 131.1070626 number

why result is pending even though use async/await ?

Comment: You didn't `await` the call to `placeObjFunc`: `await placeObjFunc()` is needed.

Comment: return [lat, lng];

Comment: thanks for your comment.
return [lat, lng]; is not Promise.
why await ahead of placeObjFunc() is need ?

Comment: `return [lat, lng]; is not Promise` the return value from an `async` function is *always* a Promise - the main point of `async`/`await` is to make code **inside** the `async` function easier to write (no need for `.then`s all over the place) - however, an `async` function does not make asynchronous code synchronous, it returns a Promise, for which the caller must `await` or use `.then` to access the result of the Promise resolution

Comment: This is one of the most common misconceptions about async/await - that it can somehow make asynchronous results available synchronously ... nothing can do that.

Answer (score 0):

try adding await to the placeObjFunc() call as well.

```
const placeObjFunc = async () => {
      let placeObj = await getLongLat(parseStr.address);
      let lat = placeObj.lat;
      let lng = placeObj.lng;
      console.log("lat, lng: ", lat, lng, typeof lat);
      return [lat, lng];
    };
let lat_lng = await placeObjFunc();
```